# Get cached items from RecyclerView

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I have many items in the ItemsSource of my `MvxRecyclerView`. Is it possible to know which ones are currently "cached" and not being referenced by any of the view holders? (and will be re-binded when scrolled to its position)

I need to know this because the items contain images and I want to free the memory when they are not visible and too much memory is being used.

I'm using MvvmCross but an answer in plain Android would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `onViewRecycled` on your recyclerview, add the images you want to free up into a stack (or immediately free them up upon view recycling)

Comment: When `onViewRecycled` is called, the `DataContext` is already set to null so I have no way of knowing which image to free.

Comment: I still used this method, just set a `Tag` on the views so I can keep track of which model is being recycled from the view.